# Quantum measuring simulation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, measurements, simulations, quantum-states

Hi I want to understand a concept that I been thinking about. I'm trying to simulate the energy measurement of a system (a many body quantum system to be precise), and I'm trying to simulate a quantum way of measuring the energy.

The energy can be defined as the expected value of the Hamiltonian,

$$\langle H\rangle_{\psi}=\langle\psi | H |\psi \rangle = E_{\psi}$$

Numerically if we have the state and the Hamiltonian only multiplying matrices we get the result of $E$.

But in quantum measuring the process is different. Normally we choose a H-diagonalizing basis $|a_i\rangle$,associated to a energy $E_i$, and we measure this Hamiltonian in this basis, so we can get different results,
$$\text{Measuring} \ \ |\psi\rangle  \qquad P_1 \quad \text{of obtaining} \quad  E_1$$
$$\qquad \qquad \quad \quad \ \qquad P_1 \quad \text{of obtaining} \quad  E_1$$
$$\qquad \qquad \quad \quad \ \qquad P_2 \quad \text{of obtaining} \quad  E_2$$
$$\qquad \qquad \quad \quad \ \qquad \cdots $$
$$\qquad \qquad \quad \quad \ \qquad P_n \quad \text{of obtaining} \quad  E_n$$

And with that we compute **statistically** the energy,

$$E_{\psi}=\sum P_i \ E_i$$

Contrary to the numerical method where we only need to do 1 calculus $\langle\psi | H |\psi \rangle$.

How can we simulate this statistical process numerically? I mean, measure the energy of an state under a Hamiltonian $H$ but following this statistical behaviour.

Comment: I assume that $| \psi \rangle$ is not an eigenstate of $H$ here, and that $H$ has a discrete spectrum. If that is the case, how do you find the probabilites $P_i$? If you know how to do that, then I believe your question boils down to "how do I simulate random sampling from a known discrete probability distribution?".

Comment: Yes, $|\psi\rangle$ is a general state, in this case for measuring $P_i$ you do it repeating the measure big number of times $N$. And you can compute $P_i=\frac{\text{Counts result is E_i}}{N}$. And so, yes, I suppose the question can be reduced to that

Comment: Hint: if you write $| \psi \rangle = \sum_i c_i |a_i \rangle$ where the $| a_i \rangle$ are your energy eigenstates, what is the interpretation of $|c_i|^2$...?

Comment: If you want to sample from a discrete probability distribution, the most straightforward way is to uniformly pick a number $x$ from [0, 1] (any random number generator can do this) and then assign it energy $E_1$ if $0 < x < P_1$, assign $E_2$ if $P_1 < x < P_1 + P_2$ etc. cumulatively.